# Detect memory leaks with FastMM and the exitcode

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, fastmm

I have an idea to enable FastMMs memleakreporting in the nightly automatic build. The messagebox should of course be disabled. 
The simplest would probably be if the applications exitcode was > 0 if there was a memleak. I did a quick test and the exitcode was 0 with a memleak and FastMM.

So my question is how can I detect if there was a memleak in FastMM to set the exitcode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For my previous Delphi project I used MemCheck. It created text log file with all leaks it detected. I like this way of reporting and I see that FastMM has option do create such file: in `FastMM4Options.inc` there is `LogErrorsToFile`. This way you need to check log file and not check exitcode.

Comment: That was a way of course. I use Finalbuilder so it should be easy to detect that memleak file.

Answer (score 2):

I modified "procedure CheckBlocksOnShutdown(ACheckForLeakedBlocks: Boolean);" for my current customer to set the exitcode, so I could easily check in DUnit if a spawned process had a mem leak.
I added a line at the end of the procedure:

```
  ...
  {$ifdef UseOutputDebugString}
  OutputDebugStringA(LLeakMessage);
  {$endif}
  ExitCode := 1;     <-- added this one
  if Assigned(OnMessage) then
    OnMessage(LLeakMessage);
  ...
```